# Drupal User registration - other unique key possible?

Tags: drupal, registration

after a long time being out of the development area, somebody has asked me to create a new Drupal site.

For user registration, they want to use a different unique key than the default email address.
In this case, they want to have the TVA number (which is Always unique) as the unique identifier.

Is it possible to create a different way of registering ?

Thanks in advance,

Davy

Comment: need some more clarification about your request.  did you want a special unique key while registration user must be provide a predefined unique key which is drupal already knows and then allow to register or every user who register drupal assign him a unique key or attach a unique key with his/her profile ?

Answer (score 0):

The Identification module allows you to specify the login credential.

https://www.drupal.org/project/identification

> This module allows users to login with a custom identification number
>   (or string). To configure this module, the site builder creates a (or
>   specifies a pre-existing) field on the user entity. The value stored
>   in this field for a particular user can then be used as the
>   identification login credential.

More info about how and why: https://www.drupal.org/project/identification/issues/2995481#comment-12792821

Another module that provides flexibility on login: https://www.drupal.org/project/login_emailusername

Answer (score 0):

I think [Registration codes](https://www.drupal.org/project/regcode) module meets your requirement

> This module allows the site administrator to allow new account registrations only for users who provide a valid registration code.
>   This module also allows the management of these registration codes, including listing, generating, importing and exporting.
>
> The most common use of this module is medallion based registration - only users who have purchased a membership medallion (e.g. made a physical purchase entitling them) are able to register.
>
> Other uses include promotional codes, and shared private key registration.

There is so many other module exits doing same job differently 
You can also generate login keys like TVA numbers